# Using nz-select in forms and an object as a resource for nzOptions in Angular 15

Tags: angular15, ng-zorro-antd

I am using angular 15 and creating a form where I am using the following code

```
<nz-form-item nz-col nzSpan="12">
    <nz-form-label [nzRequired]="true">Employee</nz-form-label>
    <nz-form-control
        [nzErrorTip]="getErrorValidate('employee')"
        [nzValidateStatus]="getFieldValidationStatus('employee')"
    >
        <nz-select
            nzShowSearch
            nzServerSearch
            formControlName="employee"
            nzPlaceHolder="Search Employee"
            [nzShowArrow]="false"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee"
            [nzFilterOption]="nzFilterOption"
            [nzOptions]="(filteredEmployees$$ | async) ?? []"
            (nzOnSearch)="onSearchEmployee($event)"
            (ngModelChange)="log($event)"
        >
        </nz-select>
    </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

In the class, I want to set the value, when creating the form, it is not visually displayed in the template

```
@Input() employees: { value: string; label: string }[] = [];
...
this.timetableForm = this.fb.group<ITimetableFormControl>({
    employee: [{value: 1, label: 'Ben G.'}, Validators.required],
    ... });
```

There is a value in the form, but it is not displayed in the nz-select itself.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in nz-select?

The documentation says that this should work, I saw examples, but with other versions of Angular